# Firebase authentication with Parse user

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, firebase, firebase-security

I'm building an iOS (Swift) app that needs realtime chat as part of the functionality. While Parse works well for push, data storage, etc..., it doesn't support realtime. I would like to use Firebase for the realtime support, but need help authenticating to Firebase using a Parse user. I really don't know where to start with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is pretty vague so a definitive answer is not possible: here's a thought.

Firebase and Parse are two different companies and therefore require separate authentications.

If your users have a username/password type authentication in Parse, you could use the same data in Firebase and authenticate through code. i.e. User creates a new account in Parse, and an account is created in Firebase via code. When the user authenticates to Parse, it also authenticates to Firebase via code.

There are a LOT of design elements to consider in going this route:  how do you create a firebase user (in code) without your app authenticating itself as a 'super' user? Hard code credentials? That may be a security issue.

Are you going to keep two sets of user data? One in Parse and one in Firebase? What if a user needs to reset their password or account. As you can see, it can get out of control rather quickly.

You may want to consider sticking with one platform to simplify the entire process. By the sound of at least one of the requirements, Firebase can do much of what Parse can do but also give the real-time updates you need.

Comment: I agree, and sorry for being so vague. I agree with your thoughts about trying to use multiple solutions. Ideally I need Parse for Push and Firebase for realtime. I'm not aware of a solution that handles both of those. I'm also concerned about how to handle security correctly, and don't believe it can be done without creating 2 users (not ideal). I think i'm going to try using Push notifications to trigger a message reload (in place of realtime), and stick with Parse. Thanks for helping me think through this.

Comment: Sure thing. Something we've discovered is that in while some situations lend itself to a push notification, having real-time updates actually work better. e.g. in a point of sale solution; when user creates an invoice and sells a product, a push notification could be sent out notifying other terminals that the item inventory count has been reduced by one. Those terminals can react the the push (at some point). Whereas with Firebase all of the terminals instantly know the inventory has been changed by observing the inventory node in Firebase. Try exploring real time updates and see if they work