# Authenticating Parse users on Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, firebase

I have a pretty common use case that was unfortunately vaguely described in this question:

[Firebase authentication with Parse user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32812826/firebase-authentication-with-parse-user)

I am using Parse as my backend and I want to add real-time chat using Firebase.

20% of users will use chat, so it would be inefficient to replicate all users on Firebase (on Parse signup).

I would like to sign the user up in the background when he starts a chat with another user.

I believe this raises some security concerns, among others, which leads me to my question:

What is the most efficient and secure way to tackle this problem ?

Comment: Why would it be inefficient to duplicate the users in Firebase? You could create, authenticate and handle all of the users data through code so the user wouldn't know the difference. You could also leverage custom tokens for authentication or throw that all to the wind and just not auth anyone in firebase and use anonymous logins and track chat's via their email address or parse user data. Not sure what the security requirements are though.

Comment: @Jay it would be inefficient because 80% of the accounts on Firebase would not be used

Comment: Disk space is cheap - don't worry too much about data duplication. On the other hand, you could just create the users in Firebase that want to chat and then store a flag in Parse to let you know if that account had been created in Firebase (or maybe their Firebase uid?). If they want to chat and flag == false, create their Firebase account then log them in. If flag == true, just log in.

Comment: Ray, have you solved this yet?